# How to position jQuery Dialog Box "Center and Middle" of a specific <DIV>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui-dialog

I want to align the jQuery Dialog box Center to a DIV and not to the full window.

Here is my code:

**HTML**

```
<div id="Box1"><input id="openDialogButton" type="button" value="Open Dialog"></div>
<div id="Box2"></div>
<div id="Box3"></div>
<div id="dialogbox" title="Dialog Heading">
    <p>Test Message</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div {
    display:inline-block;
    height:400px;
    padding:10px;
    border:1px solid #ff0000;
    width:50%;
    vertical-align:top;
}
#Box1 {
    width:90px;
}
#Box2 {
    width:150px;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#openDialogButton").click(function () {
        $("#dialogbox").dialog({
            width: 300,
            autoOpen: false,
            modal: false,
            position: {
                my: "center",
                at: "center",
                of: $('#Box3')
            },
            buttons: {
                "Submit": function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**Here is the Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Hftm3/** (for some reason my Dialog Box is not working in this fiddle. Not sure why)

Let me know if you need any other information.

Please suggest.

Comment: Remove autoopen:false in fiddle and it will show up dialog box

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the issue is because the element is not visible in the viewport, in this case you can `scrollTo` the element then fire the dialog.

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#openDialogButton").click(function () {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#Box3").offset().top
        }, 1000, function () {
            $("#dialogbox").dialog({
                width: 300,
                modal: false,
                position: {
                    my: "center",
                    at: "center",
                    of: $('#Box3')
                },
                buttons: {
                    "Submit": function () {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/8cjk6/

Answer (score 1):

In *click the button* event you are setting the dialog. If you set the `autoOpen` to true it will be shown as soon as you click the button. I've tested it here in you jsfiddle. You only have to resize it:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#openDialogButton").click(function () {
        $("#dialogbox").dialog({
            width: 300,
            height: 200, //try this
            autoOpen: true, //try this too
            modal: false,
            position: {
                my: "center",
                at: "center",
                of: $('#Box3')
            },
            buttons: {
                "Submit": function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Also, change you CSS to match only what you need:

```
#box1, #box2, #box3 {
    display:inline-block;
    height:400px;
    padding:10px;
    border:1px solid #ff0000;
    width:50%;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

Using only `div{` as you are using will break all your divs (including the ones generated by jquery to show your dialog).